# Why do I continue to get the Tasks is not defined?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to follow the Meteor documentation here:
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections
in adding a collection and being able to get an empty array back by doing this in the console:

```
Tasks.find().fetch()
```

but instead I get this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Tasks is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong since I am following their documentation, I believe the tree structure for the imports folder which I created according to the documentation is correct and the code I have implemented so far is also as suggested from their docs.

This is the client/main.js:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';
import {Tasks} from '../imports/api/tasks';

import './main.html';

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

// templates can have helpers which are just functions and events and this
// particular event is a click event
Template.todos.helpers({
  tasks() {
    return Tasks.find({});
  },
});


Template.todos.events({

});
```

This is the imports/api/tasks.js:

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

This is the server/main.js:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Tasks} from '../imports/api/tasks';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // code to run on server at startup
});
```

This is the client/main.html:

```
<head>
  <title>tasklist</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> todos}}
  {{> info}}
</body>

<template name="todos">

</template>

<template name="info">
  <h2>Learn Meteor!</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.meteor.com/try" target="_blank">Do the Tutorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://guide.meteor.com" target="_blank">Follow the Guide</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://docs.meteor.com" target="_blank">Read the Docs</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://forums.meteor.com" target="_blank">Discussions</a></li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Comment: Can it be a missing `.js` when you import Tasks?

Answer (score 0):

`Tasks` *is* defined, but only in the scope of where it is imported. Since it was never declared as global, you won't be able to access it within your browser's console.

If you want to see the tasks (the ones you are subscribing to) in the console, just update your helper function:

```
Template.todos.helpers({
  tasks() {
    let tasks = Tasks.find({});
    console.log(tasks.fetch());
    return tasks;
  }
});
```

Or, you can check your database directly:

```
> meteor mongo
> db.tasks.find()
```

Comment: chaz, I still get the same error in the console and in the database directly, I get nothing, not even an empty array.